# Errors installing SP1 Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, wsus

Have an install of Server 2008 R2 that refuses to install SP1.

Initial error was 0x800f018.

Downloaded the System Readiness tool (Feb 2012) and ran that.  Still not fixed.

Replaced the files it couldnt update using another server.

Re-ran SP1.  Failed with 0x80070490 (Error not found or something).

Re ran the readiness tool.  55 errors of which it fixed only 15.  Huge list of KBs in the servicing\Packages directory that it cannot find or read.  Is there any hope for this server?  The server that I previously used to replace the files from is unfortunately a Test server and has since been canabalised for parts.  Am i stuck having to download every KB from the 55 listed and manually installing to try and fix this error?

Any help greatly appreciated.

edit: In fact is there a way to get the server to rebuild the servicing directory?  Not even sure I know what the purpose of it is frankly.

Comment: do you see this http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/windows-7-windows-server-2008-r2-service-pack-1-sp1-installation-error-0x800F0A12

Comment: i didnt and that looks like a good thing to try.  unfortunately i have just finished a repair install and it now seems to be going in fine.  may have been quicker your way lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this really counts as a solution but running a repair install of the OS has fixed the issue.  I am now installing SP1.